# Identifying a plant in the botanical garden of Paris

Tags: species-identification, botany

I went to the botanical garden in the "Jardin des Plantes" in Paris. In a glasshouse with the name "Serre de l'histoire des plantes" on the natural history of plants (exhibiting some ancient members of plants like ferns, Cyatheales, etc.), I found the tree-like plant on the picture attached below (the one with grass-like looking "leaves"; unfortunately, I don't have a better picture because it was a bit hidden). There was no sign labelling this particular plant, or at least I was not able to spot any. Does anyone know what type of plant this is? It was rather small, roughly 2 meters in height.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like a bromeliad called spanish moss, perhaps it's related to spanish moss, else it could be very different, a close up zoom of the leaves would be good.

Comment: Looks like Casuarina glauca ‘Cousin It’

Comment: @PolypipeWrangler thanks for the comment. That looks indeed very similar. But the plant on my picture has a stem, like a tree. On the first picture one can see it a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Given the exhibit was about primitive plants, my best guess is a [gnetophyte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnetophyta), most likely a species of [Ephedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephedra) going on appearances.

Answer (score 2):

@sir-thinksalot is correct. This is an *Ephedra* species. You can have a look at [this PDF](https://www.jardindesplantesdeparis.fr/system/files/atoms/files/doc_serre_histoire_des_plantes.pdf) to get some spatial orientation - it should be with the Gnetales. You can look which species of Ephedra are known to be cultivated in French botanical gardens via a [search](https://plantsearch.bgci.org/search?filter%5Bgenus%5D=Ephedra&filter%5Bcountry%5D=FR&filter%5Bcontinent%5D=EU&sort=name) on the BGCI database. I couldn't find a public database for the plants of the Jardin des Plantes, and it isn't mentioned on the [accompanying MNHN website](https://www.mnhn.fr/fr/les-plantes-de-nos-jardins). If you are really interested, you [can drop them a line](https://www.jardindesplantesdeparis.fr/fr/contactez-nous) and ask which species it is.